# Trouble compiling java source code to .jar

Tags: java, compiler-errors, compilation, executable-jar

I've downloaded a certain app from the internet that contains a folder called Source with all the .java source files. The app is a .jar file, which I can simply double-click to run.

I made some modifications to the source files, and I would like to compile those changes into a new .jar file.

In Terminal, I'm running the following commands:

```
javac *.java
jar cfm myApp.jar Manifest.txt *.class
```

I created the Manifest.txt file myself and it simply contains the following

```
Main-Class: myApp
```

If I run myApp.jar from the Terminal (java -jar myApp.jar) it runs fine... but if I double-click myApp.jar I get "The Java JAR file could not be launched. Check the Console for possible error messages."

All I can see in Console that may be relevant are a couple of 'Jar Launcher' processes that say `LSExceptions shared instance invalidated for timeout` and the following:

```
NSApp cache appearance: -NSRequiresAquaSystemAppearance: 0 -appearance: (null) -effectiveAppearance: <NSCompositeAppearance: 0x6000034e9ef0  (     "<NSDarkAquaAppearance: 0x6000002e54c0>",     "<NSSystemAppearance: 0x6000002e5540>" )>
```

Can anyone help me out here?

Many thanks!

(EDIT) Some more info: the app in question has a GUI, and if I open the original jar by double clicking it, the app header says JarRsrcLoader. If I open my jar file via the Terminal, the app header is simply myApp. Not sure if this helps.

Comment: 1) FYI, the command `jar cfm myApp.jar Manifest.txt *.class ` won't add any of your Java source to the .jar.  2) You seem to be running on a Mac.  And the problem seems to be with the Mac's app launcher, not the .jar itself.

Comment: 1) Not sure what you mean? Again it runs fine if I open it via the Terminal.

Comment: I meant that `jar cfm myApp.jar Manifest.txt *.class` only includes binary .class files.  It doesn't include any *.java source files (or anything else *BESIDES* the manifest and the binary .class files).   Again, the problem you're experiencing is unique to the MacOS Java launcher, which apparently uses [NSApplication](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsapplication) ... and is apparently having problems displaying the app's GUI on your Mac desktop.  I'm a Windows and Linux guy myself.

Comment: Ah I see. I was following a guide that said to use javac first to create the classes, then jar *.class to compile the classes into the jar.